# Under what legitimate circumstances might GetVersionEx produce dwMajorVersion == 7 when running under Windows XP?

Tags: winapi, version

When GetVersionEx returns successfully on Windows XP, the dwMajorVersion field of the structure it produces is supposed to have the value 5. Under what legitimate circumstances -- running under Windows XP -- might it have the value 7?

Comment: Running it under XP mode in windows 7?

Comment: @tommieb75:  Windows 7 is actually Windows version 6.1, so dwMajorVersion = 6.  Off the top of my head, I don't know what the behavior of GetVersionEx is when running in a compatibility mode.

Comment: @James: Interesting...never knew that...seems MS got the versions out of sync there... :P

Comment: "If compatibility mode is in effect, the GetVersionEx function reports the operating system as it identifies itself, which may not be the operating system that is installed" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451%28VS.85%29.aspx).  So, running under XP mode in Windows 7, I'd expect GetVersionEx to return a major version of 5.

Comment: Are you actually finding an instance where it is returning 7?  I can't see how - 6.1 is the highest, W7 & W2K8R2 etc.

Comment: A simple explanation is that GetVersionEx() returned FALSE.  Are you checking it?

Comment: shimms: Yes. But I can't describe the instance (yet). That's why I'm asking this question.

nobugz: Yes; it's returning TRUE. And I looked at the value of dwMajorVersion before GetVersionEx, too, and it wasn't 7. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not under legitimate circumstances.

But: The [Appverifier](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457063.aspx) from Microsoft often changes those fields for the apps your testing to make sure your app works on future versions of Windows correctly.

Comment: I do have AppVerifier installed, and it's configured to touch the process in question, so I bet this is the issue. It is possible we should check for specific functionality rather than call GetVersionEx (which is what Microsoft wants and why, I presume, AppVerifier screws with GetVersionEx), but it's not yet clear to me whether it's possible to do this in the case at hand.

Comment: Yup. AppVerifier was it. I turned off HighVersionLie and GetVersionEx started making sense again. You rock.

Comment: The reason AppVerifier messes with GetVersionEx is to prevent apps from checking the OS version wrong. A lot of apps get this wrong and then only work on e.g. XP but refuse to do the job on Vista.

Comment: Right. I saw that in a hundred places on the web, once I knew what to look for. Ironically, Microsoft is trying to stop people from spuriously refusing to run on new systems, but this prevents our code from doing the right thing on OLD systems. We're not looking for new functionality, we're looking for differing functionality on differing systems. On XP, one set of functionality exists, and, on Vista, another exists, and, on Windows 7, no similar functionality exists. (Does this sound like a trivia puzzle? Welcome to my world.) I filed a bug about not being able to enable HighVersionLie.